# Xamarin Forms essentials Preferences

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#persistence) on Xamarin Essentials Preferences.  I understand that the preferences will removed when the app is unistalled.

> **Persistence**
>
> Uninstalling the application will cause all Preferences to
>   be removed. There is one exception to this, which for apps that target
>   and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later that are using Auto
>   Backup. This feature is on by default and preserves app data including
>   Shared Preferences, which is what the Preferences API utilizes.

My question is, when an app is updated on iOS or Andriod is that considered uninstalling and re-installing and the preferences get removed? Or just an install and nothing is removed?

Comment: Update is not uninstall, Preferences will not been removed after you update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No an uninstall really means an uninstall. So actually remove the app and then reinstall from the store.

An update will retain the preferences.